# How can I get Tomcat that is in a Docker container and OpenShift to work together

Tags: tomcat, docker, openshift-origin, openshift-online-3

I've got a Docker container which runs Tomcat that is hosting Ozone Widget Framework. If I start OpenShift and then try to start the Docker image that contains Tomcat/OWF I get a port conflict. If I try to start OpenShift while the Docker image is running I get a similar issue.

I tried changing the Tomcat ports in these files but I cannot access OWF afterward.

conf/server.xml

\apache-tomcat-7.0.21\lib OzoneConfig.properties

How do I get Tomcat running within a docker container with openshift running?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the answer is because the Openshift console is using the port. In any case I was putting OWF inside Docker when I needed to have it inside Openshift.